# How could I specify background for this class?

Tags: html, css

I would like to edit CSS in wordpress for a tab plugin I am using.  I have the CSS

```
a.link_only.vapors-tab-link-1
```

Is there a way to assign a background to ANY class that is:

```
a.link_only.#####-tab-link-1
```

The #### is the placeholder, but I have about 20 classes with this being the only difference.

Apologies, I am not sure the correct terminology to use for this.

Comment: what element is this `#####-tab-link-1`?

Comment: Hi if any below answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try below css,

```
a.link_only.<put your element>
{
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

replace your element

Answer (score 0):

You can slelect elements by using css attribute selector

```
a.link_only[class*="tab-link-1"]
```

It will select all `a.link_only` elements having `class` attribute containing the `tab-link-1` substring.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
a.link_only[class*="tab-link-1"] {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a class="link_only one-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only two-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only three-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only four-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only five-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only six-tab-link-1"></a>
<a class="link_only seven-tab-link-1"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly.